# Make a linq query distict by two fields

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have created my entity named Rowdetails

```
Public Class RowDetails
    Private m_RecordId As Int64
    Private m_DbWorldId As Int64
    Private m_TableId As Int64
    Public Property RecordId As Int64
        Get
            Return m_RecordId
        End Get
        Set(p_Value As Int64)
            m_RecordId = p_Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property DbWorldId As Int64
        Get
            Return m_DbWorldId
        End Get
        Set(p_Value As Int64)
            m_DbWorldId = p_Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property TableId As Int64
        Get
            Return m_TableId
        End Get
        Set(p_Value As Int64)
            m_TableId = p_Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I would use linq to make a query that returns the list of entity RowDetails distinct by having the same TableId and the same  RecordId. It's possible with linq? Does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: in linq I deosn't found the function DistinctBy()

Comment: Did you read the question that the duplicate linked to, which explains the use of MoreLINQ? That will only work for LINQ to Objects, mind you.